# How to Set TextBox.Text Value while TextBox bind with MVVM in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using WPF forms and i want to know how to set `TextBox.Text` value though TextBox bind With MVVM. 
For Example: `TextBox.Text = "Hello";` I want to set this value to Text box and my text box like

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtCityName.Text = "Hello Vaibhav";
        this.DataContext = new MyTesting();

    }
}
```

My WPF Window Form Class:

Next My Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox Name="txtCityName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding CityName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="40" Width="200"/>
</Grid>
```

And Next My Model:

```
internal class MyTesting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _CityName;

    public MyTesting()
    {

    }
    public string CityName
    {
        get { return _CityName; }
        set { _CityName = value; OnPropertyChanged("CityName"); }
    }

    #region PropertyChangedEventHandler
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region " RaisePropertyChanged Function "
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
    #endregion
}
```

But NULL assigned to TextBox . How to solve this

Comment: check VS Output window for binding exceptions. make sure that you set DataContext. Code provided at the moment is not enough to reproduce the issue, please create a minimal complete example

Comment: did you set the datacontext

Comment: this.DataContext = new AddressModel();

Comment: Yes. i Set DataContext in Constructor

Comment: try Text="{Binding CityName}"

Comment: Is this will work for both as either Set direct value to text value or set value from MVVM. For Example sometimes i want to set TextBox.Text Value like txtCityName.Text="Hello" and sometimes i want it set to be from MVVM

Comment: I Updated  My Question With Complete Code please look and try and Give me Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtCityName.Text = "YourCity"` is not MVVM.

You should set the `CityName` source property instead of setting the `Text` property of the `TextBox` control.

```
<TextBox Name="txtCityName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CityName}">
```

---

```
this.DataContext = new AddressModel();

AddressModel obj = this.DataContext as AddressModel;
obj.CityName = "..."; //<--this will update the data-bound TextBox
```

Comment: This is the only problem i can not set like this i can only want to set like txtCityName.Text = ".."

Comment: I need a view model. Both Scenario is  different text box should be set with both while using view model or while using .Text.

Comment: I Updated  My Question With Complete Code please look and try and Give me Solution.

Comment: I have already told you that you need to set the value of the source property.

Comment: did you check my given code please use complete code and check what is coming i want to set value by using TextBox.Text Property

Comment: Set the binding mode to OneWayToSource. But then you won't be able update the TextBlock from the view model. It is one way or the other, not both. Basic MVVM.

Comment: How can i know on Run time that TextBox bind with which MVVM Property. Is there any way?

Comment: That's a totally different question. Please don't ask additional questions in the comments field. Ask a bew question if you have another issue.

Comment: Actually Its related to this question only. Because if i can not assign value to .Text property then i want to know which MVVm Property add with this TextBox and i can assign that value to that property in Run time

Comment: Yes. Thank you . You save my time

Answer (score 7):

**Try this:**

```
class AddressModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private string _cityName;
        public string CityName 
        {
        get {
              return _cityName; 
            }
        set {
              _cityName = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged("CityName");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }                           
}
```

**And in your Code Behind:**

```
AddressModel addressModel = new AddressModel();
addressModel.CityName = "YourCity";
this.dataContext = addressModel;
```

**Xaml:**

```
<TextBox Name="txtCityName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CityName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: I can do this but i don't want to set like this i want to set txtCityName.Text = "YourCity" like this. How i can achieve this

Comment: changing TextBox value using  txtCityName.Text = "YourCity" will change your dataContext CityName property Value. so whats the problem?

Comment: Problem is that .its not working. Value null assigned to TextBox

Comment: Yes . Above i gave you the code. I wanted to set TextBox value of two type one i can set from MVVM and Second Directly assign like txtCityName.Text = "YourCity". tHis thing i want to achieve

Comment: //My Constructor.                                                                                
      public UcCountrySetup(int CountryCode, bool isCountryCode)
        {
                string codeValue = Convert.ToString(CountryCode);
                this.DataContext = new AddressViewModel(model);
                BindFieldData(codeValue);
            }

        }

Comment: Above is my constructor and inside BinFieldData(codeValue).

Comment: txtCityName.Text ="YourCity;

Comment: the code above has to work make sure to add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your TextBox

Comment: how to write in textbox i getting error.i wrote like -> <TextBox Name="txtCityName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding CityName  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}" Height="40" Width="200"/>

Comment: You should set the CityName source property. See my answer.

Comment: This is Not Working i tried. public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            txtCityName.Text = "Hello Ishir";
            this.DataContext = new MyTesting();
           
        }
    }

Comment: I Updated  My Question With Complete Code please look and try and Give me Solution.

Comment: Set this value txtCityName.Text = "Hello Ishir"  in Loaded event and it will change the datacontext CityName property value as well